# Mongoose: bad hint when indexing on an array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-indexes

I have a Mongoose model like

```
const OffersSchema = new Schema({ 
    storeIdList : [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Stores',
        required: true
    }],
    status: {
        type: String, 
        required: true, 
        enum: ['INACTIVE', 'ACTIVE', 'SUSPENDED'],
        default: 'INACTIVE'
    }
   // ...some other fields...
})
OffersSchema.index({"storeIdList":1,"status":1,"_id":-1})
```

And later I'm querying:

```
let index = {"storeIdList":1,"status":1,"_id":-1}
let docs = await Offers.find({}).hint(index)
```

And I'm getting an error "planner returned error: bad hint".
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: could it be that my enum field is indeed an array, and then one can not have 2 multikey fields in a single index? reference: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-multikey/

Comment: Yes. .As per MongoDB, You cannot create a compound multikey index if more than one to-be-indexed field of a document is an array.

Comment: my doubt is if my `status` field considered as an array or a string... isn't it a string?

Comment: It will be a string. Do you have any other information on the error message other than "planner returned error: bad hint"

Comment: no, that's the only information

Comment: Can you try running the same query from mongo shell?

Comment: I've found the problem: when I was testing, I changed the index... However, I hadn't cleaned up the previously built indexes. And because of that, my "new index" was not being found, giving the `bad hint` error. It seems the indexes are not re-created automatically... I had to drop the database and built them again.